# Entire solutions of finite difference equations

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $(E):\ \sum_{k=0}^n P_k(z)g(z+k)=0$ with the $P_k\in\mathbb C[z]$ a finite differences equation in $\mathbb C$.

Is it true that every any entire solution $g$ of (E) 
of exponential type $<\pi$ is an exponential polynomial?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean $g(z+i)$?

Comment: Is my edition correct?

Comment: It's best to avoid using $i$ as a summation index in contexts
such as this where $i$ might be needed as a square root of $-1$
(e.g. one natural thing to try is the Laplace transform, 
whose inversion involves complex exponentials).  Better to sum
over $j$, $k$, or $m$.

Comment: Alexandre > Thanks your edit was correct. Following Noam, I changed the summation index $i$ by $k$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. Function $g(z)=(e^z-1)/z$ is entire, of exponential type $1$,
is not an exponential polynomial, but it satisfies the equation
$$(z+2)g(z+2)-(1+e)(z+1)g(z+1)+ezg(z)=0.$$
Ref. J-P Bezivin et F. Gramain, Solutiuons entieres d'un systeme
d'equations aux differences, Ann. Inst. Fourier, Grenoble, 43 (1993) 792-814.

Notice that you can modify this example to achieve arbitrarily small exponential type.

Edit. There exists also such equations with entire solutions of smaller growth, of order
less than one. This paper has explicit examples with order $1/3$ and $1/5$:
K. Ishizaki and N. Yanagihara, Wiman-Valiron method for difference equations,
Nagoya Math. J., 175 (2004) 75-102.

Comment: Beautiful counter-example. Thanks a lot